# Automate the Boring Stuff With Python Madlibs: Trouble with Replacing Matched Regex (Losing Punctuation Marks)

Tags: python, regex

This is my code:

```
import os, re

def madLibs():
    madLibsDirectory = 'madLibsFiles'
    os.chdir(madLibsDirectory)
    madLibsFile = 'panda.txt'
    madLibsFile = open(madLibsFile)
    file = madLibsFile.read()
    madLibsFile.close()

    wordRegex = re.compile(r"ADJECTIVE|VERB|ADVERB|NOUN")
    file = file.split() # split the madlib into a list with each word.
    for word in file:
    # check if word matches regex
        if wordRegex.match(word):
            foundWord = wordRegex.search(word) # create regex object on word
            newWord = input(f'Please Enter A {foundWord.group()}: ') # recieve word
            file[file.index(word)] = wordRegex.sub(newWord, foundWord.group(), 1)  
    file = ' '.join(file)
    print(file)

def main():
    madLibs()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem line is `file[file.index(word)] = wordRegex.sub(newWord, foundWord.group(), 1)`.

When my program runs across the word ADJECTIVE, VERB, ADVERB, and NOUN it will prompt the user for a word and replace this placeholder with the input. Currently this code correctly replaces the word HOWEVER, it does not keep punctuation. 
For example here is panda.txt:

> The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN
>   was unaffected by these events.

When I replace VERB with say "ate" it will do so but remove the period: "...and then ate A nearby...".

I'm sure this answer isn't too complicated but my REGEX knowledge is not fantastic yet unfortunately. 
Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's unrelated to your disappearing punctuation issue, but it's a pretty bad idea to reuse variable names for different things the way you are doing for `madLibsFile` (which is both a file name and a file object), and `file` (which is the text from the file, and then a list of words). I'd suggest using different variable names, or skipping the unneeded variables for the intermediate steps, and doing several things at once (e.g. `madLibsFile = open('panda.txt')` with no variable for the filename). I'd also recommend using a `with` statement to make sure the file gets closed.

Comment: @Blckknght yes I am aware that is bad practice. The file opening part of this code is quite messy and a product of some weird experimenting I was doing earlier. I didn't bother to fix it before submitting this question though I probably should have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've correctly identified the line that has the problem:

```
file[file.index(word)] = wordRegex.sub(newWord, foundWord.group(), 1)
```

The problem with this line is that you're replacing only a part of `foundWord.group()`, which only contains the matched word, not any punctuation marks that appear around it.

One easy fix is to drop `foundWord` completely and just use `word` as the text to do your replacement in. The line above would become:

```
file[file.index(word)] = wordRegex.sub(newWord, word, 1)
```

That should work! You can however improve your code in a number of other ways. For instance, rather than needing to search `file` for `word` to get the correct index for the assignment, you should use `enumerate` to get the index of each `word` as you go:

```
for i, word in enumerate(file):
    if ...
       ...
       file[i] = ...
```

Or you could make a bigger change. The `re.sub` function (and the equivalent method of compiled pattern objects) can make multiple substitutions in a single pass, and it can take a function, rather than a string to use as the replacement. The function will be called with a match object each time the pattern matches in the text. So why not use a function to prompt the user for the replacement word, and replace all the keywords in a single go?

```
def madLibs():
    madLibsDirectory = 'madLibsFiles'
    os.chdir(madLibsDirectory)
    filename = 'panda.txt'           # changed this variable name, to avoid duplication
    with open(filename) as file:     # a with statement will automatically close the file
        text = file.read()           # renamed this variable too

    wordRegex = re.compile(r"ADJECTIVE|VERB|ADVERB|NOUN")

    modified_text = wordRegex.sub(lambda match: input(f'Please Enter A {match.group()}: '),
                                  text)     # all the substitutions happen in this one call

    print(modified_text)
```

The `lambda` in the call to `wordRegex.sub` is equivalent to this named function:

```
def func(match):
    return input(f'Please Enter A {match.group()}: ')
```